# Getting the current process creation time in Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc

How do I get the current process creation time using c/c++ on Linux? 
When I'm opening the file /proc//stat
The output is just a bunch of numbers. How do I know which one of them is the creation time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc) lists the order and meaning of the values of `/proc/[pid]/stat`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598145/how-to-retrieve-the-process-start-time-or-uptime-in-python/2598284#2598284) more information.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look into `man 5 proc`. On my system, the 22nd entry is the start time.