# Convert "jiffy" time

Tags: python, datetime

On linux, I am writing a script in python to process the file `/proc/net/xt_recent/PORTSCAN`, which looks lke this:

```
src=123.45.67.89 ttl: 64 last_seen: 4298265432 oldest_pkt: 1 4298265432
src=132.45.67.89 ttl: 64 last_seen: 4298265432 oldest_pkt: 1 4298265432
src=231.45.67.89 ttl: 64 last_seen: 4298265432 oldest_pkt: 1 4298265432
```

The last column (ie, 4298265432) is AFAIU time in "jiffy" format.

How can I convert it to something human sensible in python? For example, I would like to know how many seconds have passed since.

Comment: it is not a duplicate. I don’t see anything that would answer my question.

Comment: I need to do it in python, not in C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to convert jiffies, you are going to have to start by finding your kernels constant value for `HZ`.  You could do this by using `os.sysconf`:

```
import os

sc_clk_tck = os.sysconf_names['SC_CLK_TCK']
HZ = os.sysconf(sc_clk_tck)
```

From here you want to find the system boot time:

```
with open('/proc/stat') as f:
    for ln in f.readlines():
        if ln.startswith('btime'):
            btime = int(ln.split()[1])
```

Take this value and add it to your jiffy values you want converted divided by `HZ`:

```
(packet_jiffy / HZ) + btime
```

You could pass this value on to `time.ctime` and/or subtract it from `time.time`.

```
import os
import time

sc_clk_tck = os.sysconf_names['SC_CLK_TCK']
HZ = os.sysconf(sc_clk_tck)

with open('/proc/stat') as f:
    for ln in f.readlines():
        if ln.startswith('btime'):
            btime = ln.split()[1]


packet_time = (packet_jiffy / HZ) + btime
print time.ctime(packet_time)
print "Seconds ago %d" % (time.time() - packet_time)
```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598145/how-to-retrieve-the-process-start-time-or-uptime-in-python) has more information dealing with converting jiffies.