# Python equivalent of Perl $^BASETIME

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a python module whose responsibility is to interpolate timestamp. I have a use case where I want to get process start time whenever a function in this module is called.

In Perl equivalent of this module, I used $^BASETIME, $^T to get the process start time. Is there a similar way in python also?

I referred to this question ([How to retrieve the process start time (or uptime) in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598145/how-to-retrieve-the-process-start-time-or-uptime-in-python)). Is there any other way except using ps?

```py
import time

def get_process_start_time():
    return time.time()
```

Comment: The process is still identical to the answers in the question you linked: [How to retrieve the process start time (or uptime) in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598145/how-to-retrieve-the-process-start-time-or-uptime-in-python). None of them require you to isolate the start time to a particular module.

Comment: The intent behind this question is to check if we have perl special variables support in python

Answer (score 0):

Upon more deeper investigation, I found that I can use 'create_time' method of Process to get start time of process anywhere in the code.

```py
import os
import psutil

psutil.Process(os.getpid()).create_time()
```

Comment: This is [covered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4559733/1394393) in the question you linked.